# Waiting on two inputs in Haskell, simultaneously

Tags: haskell, concurrency, io

The title may be a bit vague. This is what I mean:

Say I have two ways of getting input to my program. The first is via the keyboard, using the function `getLine` which blocks until a line is read. The other is, say, via a `TChan`, where using `readTChan chan` will also result in a block until a value is present in the channel, whereupon it will be read.

What I want to accomplish is being able to wait for **both** values, using a single thread and not allowing my CPU to jump to 100%. The moment one of the two values is available, it is fetched and the program resumes. (Say, using `Either` to notify which of the two values was received.)

Is this possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about having one IO-thread call getLine, and put its result in the TChan as well? Sounds to me like it should work..

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use a single thread? What if, for example, you would neet to wait for 3 inputs? Or 5? Or 10?

Why the arbitrary restrictions?

Comment: I'm guessing you have some code where multiple threads were in use and you had 100% CPU? You might want to post the code so others can see why: the correct solution is threads and it may simply be an implementation problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think "using a single thread" makes sense here. You must already be using multiple Haskell threads anyway to write to the `TChan`. You should use two Haskell threads to do this, and use an `MVar` or similar to communicate the first result to arrive. For example:

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan

main = do
   chan <- newTChanIO
   forkIO (threadTChanWrite chan)
   threadMultiplexedRead chan

threadTChanWrite chan = do
   threadDelay 5000000
   atomically $ writeTChan chan 3

threadMultiplexedRead chan = do
   mvar <- newEmptyMVar
   forkIO (threadKeyboardRead mvar)
   forkIO (threadTChanRead mvar chan)
   v <- readMVar mvar
   print v

threadKeyboardRead mvar = do
   str <- getLine
   putMVar mvar (Right str)

threadTChanRead mvar chan = do
   v <- atomically (readTChan chan)
   putMVar mvar (Left v)
```

A proper implementation would probably clean up the threads left lying around afterwards, btw.

Answer (score 5):

> I have two ways of getting input to my program

You should be able to use 2 threads, one per input source, which wait on their respective inputs, writing the result to a shared channel or mvar governed by a third thread.

Comment: @Charles You're missing the point. It's rather pointless to not use more than one thread, and the guy fails to even say why.

Comment: He doesn't need to say why, and I don't see how we know that the wish is pointless.

Comment: I presume the OP is expecting OS threads, not Haskell threads (continuations). Since Haskell threads are just two continuations this is really a better soln... In fact, all our solutions use multiple Haskell threads to interleave IO, as indeed the accepted answer does...

Answer (score 3):

There is the `race :: IO a -> IO b -> IO (Either a b)` helper function in the "async" package on hackage.

Runs two IO actions concurrently, so one could be your `getLine` and the other blocking on an `MVar` or whatever. Returns an `Either` indicating which one returned first (the other is canceled).

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:race

Comment: IMO this is the correct answer. The accepted answer is overly complicated and this answer performs the tidyup that the accept answer says is required. You have to have a good reason to use `forkIO` instead of `async`.